# jQuery mouseenter one to modify another class's CSS

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, mouseevent

I have three nested tabs from which I need the following:

1. Special formatting (highlighting) should be applied when the mouse hovers over one of the nested tabs
2. When the mouse **isn't** hovering over any of the tabs, the active tab should be highlighted
3. When the mouse **is** hovering over one of the inactive tabs, the active tab should take the same non-highlighted formatting as the other (inactive) tab

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>REPORT TITLE</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <!--- Main tab functionality --->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".tab_content").hide();
       $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

       $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
           $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
           $(".tab_content").hide();
           var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
           $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
       });
   });
   <!--- Site/sub tab functionality --->
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".sub_content").hide();
           $(".sub_content:first").show(); 
           $("ul.sub_tabs li").click(function() {
               $("ul.sub_tabs li").removeClass("active_sub");
               $(this).removeClass("inactive_sub");
               $(this).addClass("active_sub");
               $("ul.sub_tabs li").not(".active_sub").addClass("inactive_sub");
               $(".sub_content").hide();
               var activeSubTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
               $("#"+activeSubTab).fadeIn();
           });
       });
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.inactive_sub').hover(function(){
               $('.active_sub').toggleClass("active_deselect");
           });
       });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="wrap">
       <h1>REPORT</h1>
       <ul class="tabs">
           <li class="active" rel="tab1">BY CYCLE</li>
           <li rel="tab2">BY MONTH</li>
           <li rel="tab3">SUMMARY</li>
       </ul>
       <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
           <br /><br />
           <ul class="sub_tabs">
               <li class="active_sub" rel="sub1">UTAH</li>
               <li rel="sub2">ARIZONA</li>
               <li rel="sub3">OHIO</li>
           </ul>
           <br />
           <div id="sub1" class="sub_content">
               S1
           </div>
           <div id="sub2" class="sub_content">
               S2
           </div>
           <div id="sub3" class="sub_content">
               S3
           </div>
       </div>
       <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
           <br />
           <p>T2</p>
       </div>
       <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
           <br />
           <p>T3</p>
       </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>


   /* RELATED CSS */

   ul.sub_tabs {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
   }

   ul.sub_tabs li {
       float: left;
       margin: 0;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding: 0px 21px ;
       width: 294px;
       font-weight: bold;
       background: #EEEEEE;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
       font-size: 1.5em;
       letter-spacing: 2px;
       line-height: 60px;
   }

   ul.sub_tabs li:hover {
       background: #FF9912;
       color: white;
   }

   ul.sub_tabs li.active_sub{
       background: #FF9912;
       color: white;
   }

   ul.sub_tabs li.active_deselect{
       background: #EEEEEE;
       color: black;
   }

   .sub_content {
       border-top: none;
       clear: both;
       float: left; 
       width: 100%;
       background: #FFFFFF;
       text-align: center;
   }

   sub_wrap {
       border: 1px solid #999999;
       border-top: none;
       clear: both;
       float: left; 
       width: 100%;
       background: #FFFFFF;
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: I would avoid modifying CSS properties using jQuery and use it instead to add/remove classes on elements.

Comment: And in this case you will not need mouseenter and mouseleave just `li.inactive_sub` and `li.inactive_sub:hover` in css.

Comment: I have updated the code above & included CSS - tried the toggleClass function but no luck on getting the active subtab to go to the standard formatting when an inactive tab is hovered. Edited the language in the question to be more clear too.